# Possible to run a Flask app with mod_wsgi on a specific port?

Tags: python, apache, flask

I'm trying to run a very simple flask app on a port on a network machine. My current server code looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/my_route')
def my_route():
    return json.dumps({'data': 'this is an example'})
```

Say that the IP of the machine on my network was `123.123.123.123`, and I wanted to run my app on port `5000`. I want to be able to either navigate in a browser or make a simple `HTTP` request to `123.123.123.123:5000/my_route` and get a `JSON` response.

I unsuccessfully tried to follow the [mod_wsgi Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/). I was getting `500 Internal Server` errors show after editing `httpd.conf` with a directive like this:

```
Listen 5000
NameVirtualHost *:5000
<VirtualHost *:5000>
        ServerName gcr_app

        WSGIDaemonProcess gcr_app user=apache threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/gcr_app/gcr_app.wsgi

        <Directory /var/www/gcr_app>
                WSGIProcessGroup gcr_app
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and restarting the `httpd` service.

What am I doing wrong here? Other information:

- RHEL 6.7
- Python 3.4.4
- Flask 0.12

Apache version:

```
$ /usr/sbin/httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Feb  4 2016 08:22:15
```

Let me know if there's other helpful information I could provide.

**Error Log Info**

```
[Mon Jan 30 17:55:22 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=2118): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'gcr_app' on '/etc/httpd/logs/wsgi.2109.0.1.sock' after multiple attempts.
[Mon Jan 30 17:55:26 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=2114): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'gcr_app' on '/etc/httpd/logs/wsgi.2109.0.1.sock' after multiple attempts.
[Mon Jan 30 17:55:27 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=2115): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'gcr_app' on '/etc/httpd/logs/wsgi.2109.0.1.sock' after multiple attempts.
[Mon Jan 30 17:55:46 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=2113): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'gcr_app' on '/etc/httpd/logs/wsgi.2109.0.1.sock' after multiple attempts.
[Mon Jan 30 17:57:48 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] File does not exist: /var/www/html/gcr_distance
[Mon Jan 30 17:57:48 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] File does not exist: /var/www/html/favicon.ico, referer: http://x.x.x.x/my_route
[Mon Jan 30 18:43:49 2017] [error] [client x.x.x.x] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=2116): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'gcr_app' on '/etc/httpd/logs/wsgi.2109.0.1.sock' after multiple attempts.
```

Thanks

Comment: You should post the errors your see in `/var/log/httpd/*`

Comment: Have a look through them and see if there's anything significant

Comment: Are you running Apache 2.2 or Apache 2.4? Your config is for 2.2, and that's in line with RHEL 6.7, but if you've upgraded to Apache 2.4 there's a different config format that can cause permission errors.

Comment: Is `apache` the wrong user? I just tried doing it with my own user and that also didn't work.

Comment: `Apache` mostly runs as user `www_data`

Comment: I thought that was on Debian based systems? @furas

Comment: I'm worried that I have an issue with my Python versions because my Python3 installation was something that I compiled myself on the machine and I think that `mod_wsgi` was compiled with a different version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who commented on this question. It turns out that I had an issue with the Python version that I was using to run `Flask` with and the Python version that `mod_wsgi`. Since I'm using RHEL 6.7, `mod_wsgi` had been installed with Python 2.7, whereas I had written my application using Python 3.4. This meant that `mod_wsgi` was having trouble importing the modules that I was using.

On top of this, I hadn't imported my `Flask` app properly. I had this in my `.wsgi` file:

```
import my_app as application
```

instead of:

```
from my_app import app as application
```

after changing some of the Python code to be 2.7 compatible and fixing my `.wsgi` file, I was able to run the `Flask` app on the port that I wanted.

I'll update this answer if installing `mod_wsgi` with the `pip` of my Python 3.4 version works for running the `Flask` app with Python 3.4.